# Alterar imagem de fundo de um Adapter Recycler View após click

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

É o seguinte, eu criei um `Adapter` que altera um `RecyclerView` em uma Activity que eu chamo através desta função (dentro da activity):

```
 private void gerarDatasView(CalendarJur calendario){


        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        listDatas.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        ListDatasAdapter adapter = new ListDatasAdapter();
        adapter.setDateJur(calendario.getDatas());

        listDatas.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

O `listDatas` é o `RecyclerView`.

E funciona perfeitamente conforme a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Cada item desta lista foi criado através do `onBindViewHolder` no meu Adapter assim:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewListDatas holder, int position) {
        DateJur data = datas.get(position);
        holder.diaMes.setText(data.getDiaMes());
        holder.diaSemana.setText(data.getDiaSemana());

        if(holder.getAdapterPosition() == posNow){
            holder.btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.background_date_layout_selected);
            posNow = holder.getAdapterPosition();
        }
        holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                holder.btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.background_date_layout_selected);
                // muda a cor de fundo conforme o click
            }
        });
    }
```

Quando eu clico em uma outra data a cor do fundo se altera da forma como eu quero, porém a data antiga teria que ficar com o background padrão (branco), mas ambos ficam com o background selecionado (azul) veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha pergunta:

**Como eu faço para o adaptador saber que tem que alterar o outro item para a cor padrão após um click?**

Tem como controlar isso dentro do Adapter ou eu teria que fazer de outra forma?

Como eu não queria deixar a pergunta muito extensa, coloquei os códigos que eu acho que são necessários, mas se precisar de outras informações é só pedir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma abordagem seria guardar numa variável a posição do item do `adapter` que foi clicado, assim sempre que o click fosse feito bastava alterar o fundo do item que está guardado na variável para o "normal" e por fim mudar o fundo do item clicado para o "novo".

Algo deste género:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
int posUltimoClick = -1;

public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewListDatas holder, int position) {
        DateJur data = datas.get(position);
        holder.diaMes.setText(data.getDiaMes());
        holder.diaSemana.setText(data.getDiaSemana());

        if(holder.getAdapterPosition() == posNow){
            holder.btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.background_date_layout_selected);
            posNow = holder.getAdapterPosition();
        }
        holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(posUltimoClick != -1){

                    // Vai aceder ao layout anteriormente clicado e mudar o fundo para o "normal"
                    Button btnAnt = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(posUltimoClick).findViewById(R.id."item que quer alterar o fundo");
                    btnAnt.setImageResource(R.drawable.background_date_layout_normal);
                    notifyItemChanged(posUltimoClick);
                    posUltimoClick = position;

                    // muda a cor de fundo do item clicado atualmente
                    holder.btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.background_date_layout_selected);
                }else{
                    posUltimoClick = position;
                    // muda a cor de fundo do item clicado atualmente
                    holder.btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.background_date_layout_selected);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Nota: para aceder ao `recyclerview` tem que o passar como parâmetro do construtor do `adapter`

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Boa ideia! Eu consegui de outra forma... Vou postar também depois. Não irei marcar como certa ainda pois quero testar e ver se aparecem outras respostas. Mas.. muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

A forma que eu fiz (não sei se é a melhor) foi utilizando `LinearLayoutManager` junto com uma interface interna no Adapter:

**Adapter**

```
public class ListDatasAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListDatasAdapter.ViewListDatas> {

    public ClickResponseDataItem clickItemResponse;

    public interface ClickResponseDataItem {
        void response(int position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewListDatas onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       ... código sem importância ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewListDatas holder, int position) {
        final DateJur data = datas.get(position);

       // botao de click
        holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if( posNow != holder.getAdapterPosition()){
                    holder.btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.background_date_layout_selected);
                    holder.diaSemana.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorWhite));
                    holder.diaMes.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorWhite));
                    posNow = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                    clickItemResponse.response(holder.getAdapterPosition()); // interface
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return datas.size();
    }

    class ViewListDatas extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
       ... código sem importância ...
    }
}
```

Na **activity** eu implemento a interface do adapter:

```
public class JuridicoCalendarActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ListDatasAdapter.ClickResponseDataItem {

    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    private int posIni = 0;
    private RecyclerView listDatas;
```

E insiro a função dentro dela:

```
 public void response(int position) {

        View v = linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(posIni);
        ImageButton btn = v.findViewById(R.id.btnDataJur);
        TextView text1 = v.findViewById(R.id.diaMesDataJur);
        TextView text2 = v.findViewById(R.id.diaSemanaDataJur);

        text1.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getBaseContext(), R.color.colorText));
        text2.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getBaseContext(), R.color.colorText));

        btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.background_date_layout_unselect);
        posIni = position;

    }
```

Ainda na **activity** instancio o meu adaptador da seguinte forma:

```
// configuro o LinearLayoutManager
linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
listDatas.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager); // seto no RecyclerView

adapter = new ListDatasAdapter(); // crio o adaptador
adapter.clickItemResponse = this; // seto a interface
listDatas.setAdapter(adapter); // seto o adapta
```

Desta forma, com o `linearLayoutManager` eu consigo gerenciar cada item do adapter na função `response()` da activity.

```
    // pega a view
    View v = linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(posIni);
    // altera os valores
    ImageButton btn = v.findViewById(R.id.btnDataJur);
    TextView text1 = v.findViewById(R.id.diaMesDataJur);
    TextView text2 = v.findViewById(R.id.diaSemanaDataJur);
```